# Giving type parameter to Java 8 method reference

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class with a static method like the following:

```
public class Foo {
  public static <T> T foo() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If I wanted to call `Foo.foo` and ensure the return type was `T`, I could say `Foo.<T>foo()`. How can I do the same for a method reference `Foo::foo`? I have tried `Foo::<T>foo` but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't valid?

Comment: @Sotirios intellij 13. I know that means it is not necessarily invalid Java 8 because I've seen many places where intellij reports something using "new" features as invalid but the code compiles with javac. however, unfortunately since the code will pretty much always be edited with intellij I'm constrained by what it will accept.

Comment: What does intellij _say_ or _show_? For which code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis if what I wrote is the correct way to express this, and this is just a javac intellij inconsistency, please post that as an answer and I'll ask a new question about intellij.

Comment: You could just put all the details here, ie. exception messages, actual code, etc. and we can help you now.

Answer (score 2):

The form `Type::<Arg>name` is a valid syntax but you have to put a concrete type into the argument. Outside the method `foo()` there is no type `T`, so the specific expression `Foo::<T>foo` won’t work unless you have another `T` in scope.

However, note that in most cases there is no need to specify a type argument at all. It will be inferred from the context:

```
public class Foo {
  public static <T> T foo() {
    // do something
    return null;
  }
  // you can specify type arguments
  static Supplier<String> S0=Foo::<String>foo;
  static Supplier<Integer> I0=Foo::<Integer>foo;
  // but there is no need for it:
  static Supplier<String> S1=Foo::foo;
  static Supplier<Integer> I=Foo::foo;
}
```

But note that a method like `public static <T> T foo()` makes no real sense. Since the method implementation has no possibility to detect what type the caller expects for `T`, the only value it can return is `null`. Ok, it may make sense if it acts as a placeholder only.